# Type error Xcode 6 swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

I having issues with Xcode, I connect my element (button) to an IBOutlet but when I try to access button, it gives me the <>> message where it should be a completion suggestion. I have connected correctly my storyboard with my view controller. Here's a screenshot, so you can see. I hope you can help me. Thank you. Ok, I have not enough reputation so I will put an URL to the image.

http://i61.tinypic.com/28at08x.png

Comment: Why don't you restart your xCode and do everything again?

Comment: I did, indeed the image is from a brand new project... in my original project I had the same issue so that's why I created this one. I even restarted my computer and fixed disk permission.

Comment: If there is not any other way then you can create button problematically.. :)

Comment: Ok so you are telling me that this problem cannot be fixed and a very basic feature can't be used ?

Comment: you are using beta version?

Comment: Bro I am new in swift and I heard that there is many problem occurs in beta version like its crash some time in my case.

Comment: Ok wait for other answers if anyone have. :)

Comment: I deleted the app and now I'm redownloading it :P. I hope this works. Thank you :)

Comment: Well.. that did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the app and download it again from AppStore.

Comment: I can't accept this answer now, I have to wait 2 days.... well played Stackoverflow :P